# Can you automate adding products from an online store to WooCommerce?

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, woocommerce, automation

I would like to get all the products from an account on this [Dutch webshop](http://johndevisser.marktplaza.nl/?p=1) (similar to eBay/Amazon) and add them to [this WordPress webshop](http://www.johnsmuziekboetiek.nl/) using WooCommerce. I started web development about 2 to 3 weeks ago, and I know the basics of HTML, CSS, JavaScript, Nodejs, and Express. I think I know roughly what to do, that is:

- Iterate over all the products per page.
- Grab the title, description, category, price, and photo.
- Store that information in an array with product objects.
- Get access to WooCommerce API.
- Iterate over all the products and add them to WooCommerce.

**My questions are**:

1. Is this possible?
2. Can I do it with the languages available to me?
3. What methods would you use? (e.g. how would you scrape the HTML, is there an easier way than the steps I described, would you do this using code or rather using some automation software, etc.)

This is a big project for me, so any help (on how to start) is welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right about the steps and yes that is possible. You can scrape the data with node.js as you know already, my personal preference is python when it comes to data scraping but you can do it in node.js. Node.js has HTML parser and so on. I would suggest you a few things:

- Parse the HTML data with a parser to get better access to the elements in order to get the data.
- Use some kind of data structure to store the data properly, for example: JSON, XML, CSV...
- If getting the data is a long process, get the data first as you may lose all the data while parsing if any section in your parsing system doesn't suit, parse the data afterwards.

I will bring here the code I wrote to get the data from the website you put, it's in python language but I put comments on it so you can get a better understanding about how you can get the data and write in other languages. You can also use `split` to cut the sections from HTML data, you don't even need to use a parser.

**Example:**

```py
import requests, json
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from pprint import pprint

endpoint = "http://johndevisser.marktplaza.nl/?p=1"

# Send a get request to page to get the html.
data = requests.get(endpoint).content

# Parse the html via BeautifulSoup
page = BeautifulSoup(data)

# Find 'div' elements whose 'itemscope' attributes are 'itemscope'
products = page.find_all("div", {"itemscope": "itemscope"})[1:]

# Create an empty array to store prepared data.
finalProductList = []

# Iterate over the products.
for i in products:
    # Create a dictionary object to store data properly.
    productData = {}
    # Get the title attribute from 'a' element on the current product.
    productData["title"] = i.find("a").get("title")
    # Get the href attribute from 'a' element on the current product because the real source can be useful in the future.
    productData["origin"] = i.find("a").get("href")
    # Get the image url from 'img' elements to download images.
    productData["imageURL"] = i.find("img").get("src")
    # This may look you complicated but it just finds 'span' elements value of 'class' attribute is 'subtext' and get the
    # inner text, split into two from ' '(space) to this ['€', '15,00'] and get the right part which is the second part
    # in the array which is the price and replace comma with dot to parse in float value.
    productData["price"] = float(i.find("span", {"class": "subtext"}).get_text().split(u"\xa0")[1].replace(",", "."))
    # Append the data to final data array.
    finalProductList.append(productData)

# Get json representation of dictionary.
print(json.dumps(finalProductList))
```

**Output:**

```
[
  {
    "title": "Sieb Posthuma  -  Mannetje Jas  (Hardcover/Gebonden) Kinderjury",
    "origin": "http://www.marktplaza.nl/boeken/kinderboeken/sieb-posthuma-mannetje-jas-hardcover-gebonden-kinderjury-92409632.html",
    "imageURL": "http://www.marktplaza.nl/M92409632/1/sieb-posthuma-mannetje-jas-hardcover-gebonden-kinderjury-92409632.jpg",
    "price": 12.5
  },
  {
    "title": "Estefhan Meijer  -  United Wraps    Wraps Uit De Hele Wereld",
    "origin": "http://www.marktplaza.nl/boeken/kookboeken/estefhan-meijer-united-wraps-wraps-uit-de-hele-wereld-92390218.html",
    "imageURL": "http://www.marktplaza.nl/M92390218/1/estefhan-meijer-united-wraps-wraps-uit-de-hele-wereld-92390218.jpg",
    "price": 15
  },
  {
    "title": "Daphne Deckers  -  De Verschrikkelijke Ijstaart  (Hardcover/Gebonden)",
    "origin": "http://www.marktplaza.nl/boeken/kookboeken/daphne-deckers-de-verschrikkelijke-ijstaart-hardcover-gebonden-92390182.html",
    "imageURL": "http://www.marktplaza.nl/M92390182/1/daphne-deckers-de-verschrikkelijke-ijstaart-hardcover-gebonden-92390182.jpg",
    "price": 10
  },
  {
    "title": "Adelene Fletcher  -   Bomen Aquarelleren Van A Tot Z",
    "origin": "http://www.marktplaza.nl/boeken/hobby-techniek/adelene-fletcher-bomen-aquarelleren-van-a-tot-z-92390124.html",
    "imageURL": "http://www.marktplaza.nl/M92390124/1/adelene-fletcher-bomen-aquarelleren-van-a-tot-z-92390124.jpg",
    "price": 12.5
  },
  {
    "title": "Razorlight ‎– America  (2 Track CDSingle)",
    "origin": "http://www.marktplaza.nl/cd-vinyl/singles/razorlight-america-2-track-cdsingle-92390118.html",
    "imageURL": "http://www.marktplaza.nl/M92390118/1/razorlight-america-2-track-cdsingle-92390118.jpg",
    "price": 5
  },
  {
    "title": "Twarres ‎– Children  (2 Track CDSingle)",
    "origin": "http://www.marktplaza.nl/cd-vinyl/singles/twarres-children-2-track-cdsingle-92390078.html",
    "imageURL": "http://www.marktplaza.nl/M92390078/1/twarres-children-2-track-cdsingle-92390078.jpg",
    "price": 5
  },
  {
    "title": "Tower Of Power ‎– The Very Best Of Tower Of Power - The Warner Years  (CD)",
    "origin": "http://www.marktplaza.nl/cd-vinyl/pop/tower-of-power-the-very-best-of-tower-of-power-the-warner-years-cd-92389836.html",
    "imageURL": "http://www.marktplaza.nl/M92389836/1/tower-of-power-the-very-best-of-tower-of-power-the-warner-years-cd-92389836.jpg",
    "price": 10
  },
  {
    "title": "Red Hot Chili Peppers ‎– Dani California  (2 Track CDSingle)",
    "origin": "http://www.marktplaza.nl/cd-vinyl/singles/red-hot-chili-peppers-dani-california-2-track-cdsingle-92389742.html",
    "imageURL": "http://www.marktplaza.nl/M92389742/1/red-hot-chili-peppers-dani-california-2-track-cdsingle-92389742.jpg",
    "price": 5
  },
  {
    "title": "Seth Godin  -  Icarus Deception  (Engelstalig)",
    "origin": "http://www.marktplaza.nl/boeken/management-en-economie/seth-godin-icarus-deception-engelstalig-92389542.html",
    "imageURL": "http://www.marktplaza.nl/M92389542/1/seth-godin-icarus-deception-engelstalig-92389542.jpg",
    "price": 12.5
  },
  {
    "title": "Rob Gifford  -  De Chinese Weg",
    "origin": "http://www.marktplaza.nl/boeken/reizen/rob-gifford-de-chinese-weg-92389500.html",
    "imageURL": "http://www.marktplaza.nl/M92389500/1/rob-gifford-de-chinese-weg-92389500.jpg",
    "price": 12.5
  },
  {
    "title": "Bart Leeuwenburgh  -   Darwin In Domineesland",
    "origin": "http://www.marktplaza.nl/boeken/informatief/bart-leeuwenburgh-darwin-in-domineesland-92386128.html",
    "imageURL": "http://www.marktplaza.nl/M92386128/1/bart-leeuwenburgh-darwin-in-domineesland-92386128.jpg",
    "price": 12.5
  },
  {
    "title": "Per Olov Enquist  -  Het Record  (Hardcover/Gebonden)",
    "origin": "http://www.marktplaza.nl/boeken/romans/per-olov-enquist-het-record-hardcover-gebonden-92386080.html",
    "imageURL": "http://www.marktplaza.nl/M92386080/1/per-olov-enquist-het-record-hardcover-gebonden-92386080.jpg",
    "price": 10
  },
  {
    "title": "Fred Vargas - Uit De Dood Herrezen (Hardcover/Gebonden) blauw/groene achtergrond",
    "origin": "http://www.marktplaza.nl/boeken/romans/fred-vargas-uit-de-dood-herrezen-hardcover-gebonden-blauw-groene-achtergrond-92385368.html",
    "imageURL": "http://www.marktplaza.nl/M92385368/1/fred-vargas-uit-de-dood-herrezen-hardcover-gebonden-blauw-groene-achtergrond-92385368.jpg",
    "price": 12.5
  },
  {
    "title": "Fred Vargas  -   De Omgekeerde Man   (Hardcover/Gebonden)",
    "origin": "http://www.marktplaza.nl/boeken/romans/fred-vargas-de-omgekeerde-man-hardcover-gebonden-92385304.html",
    "imageURL": "http://www.marktplaza.nl/M92385304/1/fred-vargas-de-omgekeerde-man-hardcover-gebonden-92385304.jpg",
    "price": 15
  },
  {
    "title": "David Sandes  -  Sergei Bubka's Wondermethode  (Hardcover/Gebonden)",
    "origin": "http://www.marktplaza.nl/boeken/romans/david-sandes-sergei-bubkas-wondermethode-hardcover-gebonden-92385090.html",
    "imageURL": "http://www.marktplaza.nl/M92385090/1/david-sandes-sergei-bubkas-wondermethode-hardcover-gebonden-92385090.jpg",
    "price": 10
  },
  {
    "title": "Sjoerd Kuyper  -  Sjaantje Doet Alsof  (Hardcover/Gebonden)",
    "origin": "http://www.marktplaza.nl/boeken/kinderboeken/sjoerd-kuyper-sjaantje-doet-alsof-hardcover-gebonden-92384948.html",
    "imageURL": "http://www.marktplaza.nl/M92384948/1/sjoerd-kuyper-sjaantje-doet-alsof-hardcover-gebonden-92384948.jpg",
    "price": 10
  },
  {
    "title": "Het Piratenschip     Klap Open En Bekijk  (Hardcover/Gebonden)",
    "origin": "http://www.marktplaza.nl/boeken/kinderboeken/het-piratenschip-klap-open-en-bekijk-hardcover-gebonden-92371996.html",
    "imageURL": "http://www.marktplaza.nl/M92371996/1/het-piratenschip-klap-open-en-bekijk-hardcover-gebonden-92371996.jpg",
    "price": 12.5
  },
  {
    "title": "John Topsell  -  Draken Trainen En Verzorgen (Hardcover/Gebonden)",
    "origin": "http://www.marktplaza.nl/boeken/kinderboeken/john-topsell-draken-trainen-en-verzorgen-hardcover-gebonden-92371928.html",
    "imageURL": "http://www.marktplaza.nl/M92371928/1/john-topsell-draken-trainen-en-verzorgen-hardcover-gebonden-92371928.jpg",
    "price": 15
  }
]
```

Comment: One more thing - I have to add the description as well (which is on the origin URL). Can I just iterate over the JSON, go to the origin URL and from there get the description to add it to the object later? Or should I put this extra step in your suggested for-loop straight away?

Comment: What do you mean by description? The type of product? You can just mess with it in the for loop as the website isn't that complicated and point of failure is less.

Comment: I meant when you click a [product](http://www.marktplaza.nl/boeken/stripboeken/kamagurka-het-boeiende-leven-der-sukkels-1980-92409968.html), there's a product description underneath the little heading saying "Omschrijving". I'll try to do it within the for loop, thanks again!

Comment: Oh you mean visiting and getting the data, sorry didn't read properly. You can probably do that in for loop on that particular website but be careful, many websites have request rate limits. If a website has a rate limit, you can put a sleep function to avoid that or you can add an if else handler to see if the response code was 200(OK) or not.

Comment: Amazing, thank you so much for your help. I'm gonna get right to it! My upvotes aren't visible yet, but I upvoted your answer and marked it as the best. :)

Comment: My pleasure, :).